# Desktop Freezes every second with AnyDesk client connected

Tags: drivers, 20.04, freeze, cinnamon, anydesk

I have a strange issue with AnyDesk. I can use it fine to connect to other PC's. If anyone tries to connect to me as soon as I hit accept it seems to freeze for a micro second every 1 second. The only thing that seems to freeze is the desktop. If I am on a zoom meeting I can still hear and speak with the other participants. This happens with both GDM3 and LightDM. It happens with Gnome and Cinnamon. The disk is not full (far from it) and the memory is barely being used. This is a Dell Precision 7530 laptop. Below is what is on the laptop that I am using.

```
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          64103        4560       53865         914        5677       57913
Swap:          2047           0        2047
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Baffin [Radeon Pro WX 4130/4150]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:410-40f iomemory:400-3ff irq:167 memory:4100000000-41ffffffff memory:4080000000-40801fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4400000-b443ffff memory:b4440000-b445ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:165 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ lsmod | grep amdgpu
amdgpu               4579328  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdgpu
gpu_sched              32768  1 amdgpu
ttm                   106496  1 amdgpu
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 amdgpu,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,i915
drm                   491520  16 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,i915,ttm
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$ lshw -c CPU
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-cpu                     
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: cpu@0
       size: 3860MHz
       capacity: 4300MHz
       width: 64 bits
       capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
dovid@dovid-desktop:~$
```

Comment: is this not an issue you ca raise with AnyDesk (as you presumably pay for the privilege) by raising [a support ticket](https://support.anydesk.com/Submitting_Support_Tickets)?

Comment: I called them and told them I wanted to pay to get better support. They said first in, first out. They support paid and non paid the same. Ticket opened. So far no response.

Comment: Setting nomodeet seems to "fix"t he issue so I assume it's a driver issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @david bender, Setting nomodeet in grub is a nice workaround for this issue.
The issue is still relevant event with new PC, updated ubuntu and drivers, and anydesk (2023) ...